# How to handle browser-compatibility check for your website

Tags: web-development, cross-browser, browser-support

Whenever I redesign a website, I spend a lot of time manually checking whether the new website is still supported on all major browsers by opening the website on the corresponding browser.

What is a time-efficient way of testing cross browser compatibility?

Comment: There are some web services like Browser Stack for you pay a monthly fee and can test on lots of web browsers over lots of operating systems. It's a lot simpler than managing your own virtual machines.

Answer (score 1):

The two approaches are:

1. Install all the browsers that you can on the computers that you have.

   - You'll need multiple platforms: Windows, Mac, Android, iPhone, etc.
   - Emulators and virtual machines can help.

     - [Microsoft released virtual machines for testing various versions of Internet Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575).  I can even get these to work on Linux.
     - [There are many phone simulators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464089/simulators-emulators-for-mobile-browser-testing) for testing mobile
2. Sign up for a service that has all these installed for you and lets you access them.   There are several available.  I find that is it generally cost effective to do this rather than continually having to buy (and manage) machines just for testing.  I personally use crossbrowsertesting.com